# How ATL ActiveX control exposes a Boolean value to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, activex, atl

I am creating an ActiveX control using ATL and trying to expose a property taking a Boolean value. I implemented it as below:

```
STDMETHOD(get_Visible)(VARIANT_BOOL *pVal);
STDMETHOD(put_Visible)(VARIANT_BOOL newVal);
```

In the JavaScript function, I call this by the following code:

```
MyAxCtl.Visible = true;
//MyAxCtl.Visible = "true";
//MyAxCtl.Visible = "TRUE";
//MyAxCtl.Visible = "VARIANT_TRUE";
//MyAxCtl.Visible = -1;
//MyAxCtl.Visible = "-1";
```

However, none of them works. So, my question is how to expose a Boolean value from ATL ActiveX control to JavaScript.

Moreover, anyone can tells me where can I find any document about communication between ATL types can JavaScript types? I want to find a list of ATL types that can be exposed to JavaScript.

Many thanks,
Shupining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provider the STDMETHOD's are correct and the proper JavaScript call for a Boolean is to set it to true.

While I don't see a case issue with the code you posted, make sure its "Visible" not "visisble".

When you debug is the ActiveX call being entered?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply! I have checked it, and I am sure there is no typo. and the ActiveX call is not entered. But another method with void parameter can be entered when I call it.

Comment: Interesting.  If you change the name of "Visible" to "ABCDEFGZZZ" does that work?  Visible is such a common name something else may be getting the call 1st.

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a new project and copied the code to the new project. and finally it works with the same code. it's strange but anyway it works. Thanks for all your information that let me know the type VARIANT_BOOL works with javascript.

Comment: Great to hear.  Thanks for letting everyone know.